# How to call main method on class identified by String

Tags: java, class, reflection

I'm trying to call the main method on a Java class identified by a String. In the actual program, the class identifier will be a variable, but for the moment I'm trying this. The desired parameter `main`, `newargs`, is of type String[].

```
try {       
    Class c = Class.forName("Arena");

    Class[] aarg = new Class[1];  
    aarg[0] = String[].class;

    Method m = c.getMethod("main", aarg); // Needs parameter class list
    m.invoke(newargs);
}           
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);      
}
```

First, I get a compiler warning (Athena is the name of the class I'm currently working in):

```
Note: Athena.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Then on testing I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

I feel like the primary thing is I don't know how to identify the parameter of `main()` as an array of the String class (failed to find an example of that), but maybe I'm missing more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getMethod()` you supply an array of Classes with length 1. This is somewhat incorrect; it should work due to the use of varargs, but it's pointless. The method will interpret it the same as simply providing one class. Literally adding `.class` to the expected types and separating them with commas should yield the proper result. If you had `String[]` and `int` as parameters in `main()`, it would look like `c.getMethod("main", String[].class, int.class)`.

In `invoke()`, you can ignore the first parameter and pass `null` since `main()` is a `static` method. The second is declared as a varargs parameter, but in my test this didn't work properly. I cast to a single `Object` instead of an array of length 1 of `Object`s. Here, `Object` works as a raw type since `invoke()` is uninformed as to what its parameters should be at compile time, but can cast them to the desired type at runtime.

The varargs use in `invoke()` doesn't work in this case because it expects the type `Object[]` or comma separated values that can be combined to an `Object[]`. The issue is that `String[]` is a subclass of `Object[]`. So instead of interpreting `String[]` as a single `String[]` parameter, the `invoke()` method thinks you are trying to give it a set of distinct `String`/`Object` inputs.

Internal logic:
`method.invoke(null, 1, 2, 3)` becomes `Object[]` with `int` elements. 3 separate `int` parameters
`method.invoke(null, "hello", "wow", "ok")` becomes `Object[]` with `String` elements. 3 separate `String` parameters
`method.invoke(null, String[] { "hello", "wow", "ok" })` becomes `Object[]` with `String` elements. 3 separate `String` parameters, even though we only desire one parameter that is `String[]`

Honestly this isn't your fault, the API is lacking good documentation to diagnose these issues. Feel free to ask me questions, this stuff is confusing.

```
try {       
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("Test");
    Method m = c.getMethod("main", String[].class); // Needs parameter class list
    String[] input = new String[] { "hello world" };
    m.invoke(null, (Object) input);
}           
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Long explanation missing the point while silently fixing the actual issues in the code: first, change `Class c` to `Class<?> c` to get rid of the warning, second, insert `null` before the method arguments, because the OP wants to invoke a `static` method. Whether `newargs` has the type `String[]`, is pure speculation. Since the OP did not say something about an associated warning, it may already have a non-array type.

Comment: @Holger: newargs is of type String[]. I edited the question to add that.

Comment: This did solve my problem, thanks. Suggest you edit and incorporate @Holger's added explanation, as that very much clarified the issue (and then I bet you'll get more upvotes).

Answer (score 0):

`invoke` accepts two arguments,

```
  public Object invoke(Object obj, Object... args)
```

> `obj`  the object the underlying method is invoked from args the
>
> `args` arguments used for the method call

```
Class c = Class.forName("Arena");
String[] params = null;
Method m = c.getMethod("main", String[].class); // Needs parameter class list
m.invoke(null,(Object) params);
```

Note `null` for `invoke`  as main method don’t need instance.

Answer (score 0):

i think, it would work if type of aarg was String[]. It is Class[] now.

Answer (score -1):

```
Class<? extends Demo> clazz = Demo.class;
Method mainMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
final Object[] args = new Object[1];
args[0] = new String[]{"1", "2"};
mainMethod.invoke(null, args);
```

We can use any class name instead of Demo.